# What is a good way to get the diff between complex html/xml

Tags: html, xml, perl

Hi I've got a question in regards to find the difference between 2 xml/html with perl.
I've tried a few thing so far like XML::Diff, and XML::SemanticDiff but didnt find something satisfying so far.

What I need is to get the exact position of every difference between 2 xmls (html parsed into xml). With XML::Diff I managed to find the exact position but had the problem that it is not maintained since years (thus I can't use it). With XML::SemanticDiff I had the problem that I didn't get the exact position (for the examples below: 1<->2 was equal to 1<->3).

So my question is: What is a good way to find differences ?

Example XMLs:

```
XML/HTML1: <div><b>Newsinfos<br/></b>Test1</div>
XML/HTML2: <div><b>Newsinfos<br/><br/></b>Test1<b>Test3></b></div>
XML/HTML3: <div><b><br/>Newsinfos<br/></b>Test1<b>Test3></b></div>
```

tnx

Comment: Missing a "<" in examples 2 and 3?

Comment: "Best", without further qualification, is extremely subjective.

Comment: tnx runrig: corrected it.
louis: tnx changed to a good way (as there are probably more than 1 good way)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Text::Diff library for this exact situation with success.  I believe that is the best solution, unless you are doing this on very large files, then it will start to consume too much memory.  If all else fails, you can easily shell it out to the /usr/bin/diff binary and capture the output that way.

Comment: The "files" are not large (the two xml are coming from the database and are about 20-40k at max in size)

Comment: how do you use it there? tried itr out today but managed only to get if the whole line was different or not, not what elements in the line are different.

Comment: That is the only way it works..per line.  If you need something aware of xpaths and individual nodes then this won't work.  When I did it, I formatted the XML so there was one node per line and that worked for me.